# Ruta, identify pattern and return part of it

Tags: ruta

I am working on a basic ruta script. My goal is to identify a patter, let's say a currency amount, but return just the numeric value of it.
As an example, the text could be "I paid USD54 for my new shoes". I want to identify 'USD54' so that I am sure it's a monetary value and not a quantity, but I want to get just '54' from my script so that in my downstream application I can use it as a number.

All my script as a structure like the one below, which is fine but it returns USD54 and not just 54.

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
DECLARE VarA;
DECLARE VarB;

// 2 capital letters and any number of digits
// Example USD5 , USD6700
// 
CAP{REGEXP("USD") -> MARK(VarA)}
NUM{ -> MARK(VarB),MARK(EntityType,1,2)};
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Cheers.

Comment: Your rule should output 3 annotations: "USD" (VarA), "54" (VarB), "USD54" (EntityType).  Do your expect EntityType to match only on "54" ? If so, then you should remove the indexes (1,2) in the rule.

Comment: This is the scenario. I have a piece of text to analyze that contains "USD54 and 13". I need to identify the value that refers to the currency, so I need to match USD54, but then I need an integer (54) as result of my script so that the downstream application can use it without any string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the described scenario, you would like to have as output a currency symbol (i.e. USD) and the amount (i.e. 54) as integer. In Ruta, you could tackle this structure as a single annotation `Currency` with features `symbol` and `amount`:

```
DECLARE Currency (STRING symbol, INT amount);
INT value;
(s:W{REGEXP("USD", true)} NUM{PARSE(value)}){-> CREATE(Currency, "symbol"=s.ct, "amount"=value)};
```

Since `54` is a `NUM` annotation, it has to be parsed to `INT` and stored as `value` variable. Similarly, to get the string value of the symbol annotation `W`, we pass the covered text (i.e., `s.ct`) of `W` referenced with label `s`.

Now you can access the features without any string manipulation in the downstream application.